# Drupal Feed Aggregator and Twitter integration

Tags: drupal, twitter, drupal-modules

I am currently using the Drupal feed aggregator built-in module to aggregate a bunch of RSS feeds. I also have the Twitter module installed.  I want to set things up so that all the new posts from the feed aggregator get sent out to twitter, but unfortunately the twitter module doesn't allow for that right now. Does any one know of another way to do this or a work around? I know I can create a custom module to do this but didn't want to go down that road unless I had to

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the Twitter module (it's been a while since I've used it) is that it will send out notifications to Twitter on new node creation or update. Would you be interested in [the Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds) as an alternative to the core aggregator in Drupal? That would create nodes from each feed item, instead of the Aggregator, which only creates database entries that expire. The Feeds module approach would create nodes, which would then theoretically automatically ping Twitter. See also http://drupal.org/node/403274 which I think is a similar feature request.

Comment: Trying this....Seems to work in theory but unfortunately when a feed updates it only sends the most recent post out to twitter. I will have to investigate some more

Comment: I think this will have to work for now. Luckily in that link you sent it shows the status as active....I hope they are working on it. Thanks again!

Comment: I think I found another module that will work for now - http://drupal.org/project/tweetrss